# Calling a function and passing parameters from within a closure in Swift

Tags: swift, closures

I am doing an HTTP request with `NSURLSession`, which requires a closure that will execute at the end of the request. From within the closure I am trying to call a function and pass the `returnList` object to that function.

**The Problem:** When I print out the list with the `callback()` function, it is empty, even though I have assigned a value to the list object inside the closure. What is the cause of this behaviour and what do I have to do to pass an object to a function that is called inside a closure?

```
var returnList = [ReturnList]()
    ...
    ...
    func httpRequestFunction(callback: ([ReturnList])->()){
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url){(data, response, error)  in

                if error != nil {
                    //TODO do some error handling
                    return
                }


                var xmlUtil = XMLUtil(data: data)
                self.returnList = xmlUtil.parseXML()
                println(self.returnList.count) // returns 1
                callback(self.returnList) /*the callback prints returnList.count which is then 0 */


            }

            task.resume()
     }
```

Comment: You aren't showing enough code for your question to be meaningful. What is a ReturnList? Where did `callback` come from and what does it look like? And so on.

Comment: ReturnList is just some self defined type. The list could be of any type. callback() is just some self defined function that takes a list of ReturnList objects as parameter.

Comment: Okay, so I get that you don't want to answer my questions. But since what you are describing is not the expected behavior, that makes it impossible to help you. The information needed to guess why this is happening, if it is happening, is not present in the question as you have posed it.

Comment: Have edited the code a little. It's all defined within a function that takes a callback function as a parameter, which is then called from within the closure with the list of ReturnList objects as parameter

Comment: Excellent. But the only place I can go from here is to prove to you that what you're describing is not the expected behavior. And I think you already know that. :)

Comment: I suspected it wasn't the expected behavior, which is why I posted the question. Not sure what else to post codewise. All that callback does at the moment is print out the number of elements in the list.

Comment: Yes, but what list? Without seeing the code, I can't know what it does. You are describing in _words_ what you _think_ the `callback` does, but I don't necessarily believe you. Only the code can show the facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is not normal, so something else must be going on. For example:

```
typealias ReturnList = Int
var returnList = [ReturnList]()
func httpRequestFunction(callback: ([ReturnList])->()) {
    self.returnList = [1,2,3]
    print(self.returnList.count) // prints 3
    callback(self.returnList) // prints 3
}
func test() {
    httpRequestFunction {
        list in
        print(list.count)
    }
}
```

It works perfectly. Since that isn't the sort of result you're getting, you must be doing something else wrong - but there's no way of knowing what it is, since you refuse to show any more code.

For example, you *say* that `callback` prints `returnList.count`, but of course it better not be printing `self.returnList.count` - it needs to print the count of the list *that it got as its parameter* (as in my example above). But you refuse to show it, so how do I know you're doing it right? And so on.

Another source of difficulty is that you are accessing an instance variable, `self.returnList`, from within an HTTP callback. So who knows what thread we are on? If this is happening on a background thread, some other thread could come along and change `self.returnList` between the time we `print` it and the time we call `callback` in the very next line! So again, further details would be needed.

Comment: You were right, my callback printed a completely different list.